# C# application testing connection (ping, download, upload) to the web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, connection, bandwidth

I have created a simple web service that receives data and saves it in a database. I need to create an application (or service) that will test the connection to this web service (from time to time, e.g. every 1 minute).

I need information like download, upload, ping and save them in the database. I tried NetworkInterface, but the web service is not an interface, so it cannot find it. I don't know how to test this connection and get information about it, so I need help.

Comment: Is this ok to use from third part apps like jmeter and postman ?

Comment: @Afshin I have to download the data directly from the web service. Later view in the console and save in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution 1: fully custom

High level description:

1. Create a new endpoint , something like api/healthcheck
2. Either
   a. do a mock action (save/delete false data
   b. Maintain a table or any other persistence (even a singleton would do) with statistics from recent calls
3. Add them to a class response object and return it to the caller.

#### Solution 2: Use custom telemetry

High level description:

1. Pick a service like application insight: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-insights-overview
2. Configure the telemetry if the out of the box configuration isn't enough.
3. Use the rest api to get your information

Comment: Where is the connection information such as ping, download and upload? Where can I get them when I call the endpoint?

Comment: Ping is ICMP and has nothing to do with web services. Why would you even need this metric for a web service? Do you need server ping times and why? The download and upload values can be infered by the time your GET and POST verbs take in the telemetry.

Comment: I need this data to check the web service load. A large number of computers will connect to it, in the future. Telemetry? I have to make GET and POST request and check what time is in them and it will be in kb / s? Is this time not a ping? Unless there is some library that sends and receives this data?